# Working with Recurring Appointments

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

it should be easy task, but shocked it really hard. i am binding RadScheduler with ArrayList on server site. if i use DataRecurrenceField property  on databinding it make all the schedule to recurring schedule even if they are just simple schedule. how can i manage recurring schedule at binding, here is my code

```
 public void BindScheduler()
        {
            ArrayList schedules = null;
            schedules = AdminRemoteController.GetScheduleByFFId(FfID);

            RadScheduler1.DataKeyField = "ScheduleId";
            RadScheduler1.DataStartField = "StartDate";
            RadScheduler1.DataEndField = "EndDate";
            RadScheduler1.DataSubjectField = "Subject";
            RadScheduler1.DataRecurrenceField = "RecData";
            RadScheduler1.DataRecurrenceParentKeyField = "RecId";
            RadScheduler1.DataReminderField = "Reminder";
            RadScheduler1.DataSource = schedules;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is response from Telerik and solve my problem

"It is quite possible that your RecurrenceParentID value for your appointments is "0" instead of "null" and this will cause similar unusual behavior. I would like to clarify that if it is regular appointment the appointment RecurrenceParentID should be null in order to work as expected. If that value is different than null the appointment might be considered as recurring appointment."